# Public access container in QNAP NAS server

Tags: server, reverse-proxy, portforwarding, nas, qnap

I have running **node.js** app in my docker container in Container Station in my QNAP NAS. It's working on my local network on the port I have specified.

Typically I would set reverse proxy pointing fe. `my-domain.com/my-app :80 => :<local-port>`

On NAS I have static IP provided, I have even a domain for public access `(my-server.myqnapcloud.com)` and I'd like to set up somehow my server to be visible outside. It doesn't have to be QNAP domain, I can set my own domain pointing to QNAP local address, but still I'm not able to forward local port to another in server scope.

What is the best way to setup such enviroment? It seems to be much easier without NAS at all...

Answer (score 1):

If i'm not wrong, your QNAP server is over the router. If so, you have to change some settings...

Steps to do:

1. Open a *Container Station* and find the instance of your container.
2. Go to "Settings" then "Advanced settings" and find *LAN* bookmark (sieć)
3. There must be a grid: "*Port Routing*" with 2 columns: "*Host*" and "*Container*".

   - "*Container*" - a port on which container is listening incoming **internal** connections
   - "*Host*" - a port on which QNAP server is listening incoming **external** connections. **You have to remeber this value!**
4. Close *Container Station* and open *myQNAPcloud* application
5. If you don't see the service which is responsible for port forwarding, you have to add appropriate service.
6. After that you have to execute changes in a router.

**Note:**
I've struggled with the configuration of PostgreSQL database installed on container. Finally, i was able to achieve that. Here is detailed description: [How to enable remote connections to your PostgreSQL server (in Container Station) on QNAP NAT server over the router](https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/1277184/How-to-enable-remote-connections-to-your-PostgreSQ)

Hope this help.